# How to add tabs in custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I am creating a custom module. In module created a block view (`phtml`) and trying to add the custom tabs.
I have tried below:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">How can I download eBooks?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">What format are Bookstore eBooks?</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Once you complete your eBook purchase, the download link for your eBook will be available in your account.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Bookstore eBooks can be downloaded as a PDF, EPUB or MOBI file. They can also be viewed online.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
require(['jquery','jquery/ui'],function($, tabs) {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>
```

Also tried the

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/tabs'
], function($){
```

Even added the CSS directly in phtml (testing only).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

But they are not working.
Am I missing anything? Please let me guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to change your structure to something like this:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab-item" data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'>
        <div class="tab-title item-title" data-role="collapsible">
            <span data-role="switch"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content item-content" data-role="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this will work with a foreach also, you can set the switch to an `<a>` element with href that is the `tab-item` id ( if you want ) to have that anchor go-to-section

**UPDATE**

```
require([
     'jquery',
     'jquery/ui'
     ],
     function($, tabs) {
          //Ajax here
     }
);
```

you should add the tabs init function in the something like this

```
$(Element_populated_by_Ajax).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(".tabs").tabs();
});
```

Comment: I have tried it already and it works but I need to do it as mentioned in my question using require JS.

Comment: because it doesn't work as a Ajax call response data.

Comment: does the content from the tab comes with ajax? or the entire page is with ajax? You need to give me more information so I can help

Comment: entire page come in ajax response

Comment: Updated answer, try the new sollution, should work without issue

Comment: No need to add the function($, tabs)
It directly works $(".tabs").tabs();